# Однородные/неоднородные приложения

Tags: пунктуация

Являются ли приложения в предложении однородными? "Концерт с народным артистом СССР(,) лауреатом государственной премии(,) солистом Большого театра Артуром Эйзеном произвел огромное впечатление". И "лауреат международных конкурсов(,) солист государственной филармонии Андрей Иванов".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**В этих предложениях все приложения однородные и пишутся через запятую.**

*"Концерт с народным артистом СССР, лауреатом государственной премии, солистом Большого театра Артуром Эйзеном произвел огромное впечатление". И "лауреат международных конкурсов, солист государственной филармонии Андрей Иванов"*.

Comment: Можете пояснить почему? Ведь вроде как приложения характеризуют предмет с разных сторон: лауреат - звание, солист - роль в оркестре.

Comment: Они не характеризуют предмет с разных сторон, это всё профессиональные характеристики Иванова: звание, звание, должность. Это очень близкие вещи.

Comment: И Эйзена тоже.)

Comment: Если бы это была должность, запятой бы не было: звания и должности - неоднородные приложения:первый заместитель министра обороны генерал армии – должность и воинское звание; главный конструктор проектного института по строительному машиностроению для сборного железобетона инженер – должность и профессия. А вот солист - это не должность и не профессия(профессия -артист, вокалист,танцор), это степень лидерства, т.е. очень похоже опять же на звание,

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение!